# Identify this variegated houseplant with long leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

The mature leaves are 6-8 inches long.

At first, I thought it could be an avocado or money tree plant, but managed to rule those out.  Money tree has multiple leaves per node, and the leaves are distinctly different from an avocado.

[image: whole plant]

[image: woody Stem]

[image: Variegated Leaf Detail]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's variegated or has a most peculiar nutrient deficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a heavily variegated croton plant. Possibly TAMARA Croton Plant as described [here](https://www.emeraldgoddessgardens.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=228) or [here](https://garden.org/plants/view/711481/Croton-Codiaeum-variegatum-Tamara/)

Provide very bright light and watch out for spider mites on the undersides of the leaves.  It responds well to being cut back if it gets straggly

Comment: Thank you, **kevinsky**!  I had not seen this kind of variegation on a Croton before, but I'm pretty sure you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

After looking around online and re-examining my coworker's plant, I'm sure this is the "Andrew" cultivar as seen [here](http://looking-at-plants.com/plants_a_-_z/codiaeum_variegatum_%E2%80%98andrew%E2%80%99) in case anyone wants the specifics.